# Elegant way to find out if a Java 8 stream filter has filtered something

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of `Item` fetched from a database.

I do something like:

```
List<Item> list;
list.stream()
    .filter( i -> i.condition() )
    .mapToLong( Item::asLong )
    .sum()
    ;
```

Now I want to know, if the filter has filtered out something so I could delete this from my database where it is no longer needed.

I could do:

```
List<Item> list2 = list.stream()
    .filter( i -> i.condition() )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
    ;

int theSizeIWant = list2.size();

list2.stream().mapToLong( Item::asLong )
     .sum()
     ;
```

but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution which doesn't need to create the intermediate list.

Comment: list2.size() in second snippet is strange

Comment: `for()` loop is elegant ... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution would be to partition the Stream with the predicate and sum the values. Partitioning is done with [`partitioningBy(predicate, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-). In this case, the predicate would be your filtering function and the downstream collector would be [`summingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-) to sum the values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Boolean, Long> map = 
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                Item::condition, 
                Collectors.summingLong(Item::asLong)
            ));
    long sumWithTrueCondition = map.get(true);
    long sumWithFalseCondition = map.get(false);
}
```

The map will contain the sum where the predicate is `true` (resp. `false`) with the `true` key (resp. `false`).

This way, if something has been filtered, `sumWithTrueCondition` will be strictly greater than 0. Furthermore, you can get the total sum by adding `sumWithTrueCondition` and `sumWithFalseCondition`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do something like this.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Item>> partitions =
    list.stream.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i.condition()));
```

Where `partitions.get(true)` will get you the good ones and `partitions.get(false)` will get you the ones to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to count the bad elements in the lambda expression:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "12", "4", "5");
List<String> badOnes = new ArrayList<>();

strings.stream()
       .filter(s -> {
         boolean returnValue = !s.contains("1");
         if (!returnValue) {
           badOnes.add(s);
         }
         return returnValue;
       })
       .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

System.out.println(badOnes);
```

Comment: Be warned, stateful filter here. This goes against the contract of `filter`.

Comment: Your write to `badOnes` is not thread-safe here!  This is an accident waiting to happen.  Use a thread-safe construction like setting an `AtomicBoolean` instead.

Comment: Actually, @Tunaki, the filter parameter is not stateful, nor is it interfering, because the state it writes is not used as an input into any calculation used by the stream pipeline.  But, it is still wrong, because it is side-effect-ful, and the side-effects aren't thread-safe.

Comment: @BrianGoetz could you explain why thread-safety is a requirement here? Wouldn't that only be a concern if a parallel stream was being used?

Comment: @kingds It depends.  This is sort of like saying "it's safe to put oily rags on the stovetop if it is not on." And that's true, but ... it's still a pretty irresponsible move. Are you absolutely, positively sure that, in the 20 year future maintenance of the code, no one will ever be tempted to turn the stream parallel?  Are you willing to bet your company's business on it? As my earlier comment states, this is an (easily avoided) accident waiting to happen. Sure, as long as you never touch it again, its probably OK, but does that really describe how software is maintained in the real world?

Comment: @BrianGoetz that makes sense, thanks for the response. I had interpreted "an accident waiting to happen" as meaning that a race condition could cause this code, in its current form, to behave differently than expected. But from a maintenance standpoint I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

This alleviates the intermediate list, it still need a second calculation though. If something doesn't pass the condition, it wont pass further down the stream, and won't get counted.

```
int count = 0;
```

count has to be an instance variable, and then you can do this:

```
List<Item> list;
list.stream()
    .filter( i -> i.condition() )
    .mapToLong( (item) -> { count++; return item.asLong(); } )
    .sum();

boolean isFiltered = list.size() > count;
```